# Android Send List of custom Class with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have made my own class called Alarm. I then made a List called AlarmList. I wish to send this list between two Activities, but nothing seems to get sent.

Here is my code:

The Alarm class:

```
public class Alarm {
    private String Name;
    private List<String> Days;
    private String Id;
    private int Hour;
    private int Minute;
    private Uri Ringtone;

public Alarm(String newId, String newName, int newHour, int newMinute, Uri newRingtone, List<String> newDaysList){
    setId(newId);
    setName(newName);
    setHour(newHour);
    setMinute(newMinute);
    setRingtone(newRingtone);
    setDays(newDaysList);
}

public String getName(){
    return Name;
}
public void setName(String newName){
    Name = newName;
}

public List<String> getDays(){
    return Days;
}
public void setDays(List<String> newDaysList){
    Days = newDaysList;
}
public void addDay(String newDay){
    Days.add(newDay);
}

public String getId(){
    return Id;
}
public void setId(String newId){
    Id = newId;
}

public int getHour(){
    return Hour;
}
public void setHour(int newHour){
    Hour = newHour;
}

public int getMinute(){
    return Minute;
}
public void setMinute(int newMinute){
    Minute = newMinute;
}

public Uri getRingtone(){
    return Ringtone;
}
public void setRingtone(Uri newRingtone){
    Ringtone = newRingtone;
}
}
```

MainActivity:

```
private List<Alarm> AlarmList;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtra("AlarmList")){
        AlarmList = (List<Alarm>) intent.getSerializableExtra("AlarmList");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        AlarmList = new ArrayList();

        // This part is for debugging purposes
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        List<String> rList = new ArrayList<>();

        Alarm tempAlarm = new Alarm("id1", "name1", 10, 20, myUri, rList);
        AlarmList.add(tempAlarm);
        tempAlarm = new Alarm("id2", "name3", 11, 21, myUri, rList);
        AlarmList.add(tempAlarm);
        tempAlarm = new Alarm("id3", "name3", 12, 22, myUri, rList);
        AlarmList.add(tempAlarm);
        // This part is for debugging purposes
    }

public void addAlarm_Click(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddAlarmActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("AlarmList", (Serializable) AlarmList);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void deleteAlarm_Click(View v) {
    for (Alarm x: AlarmList) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + x.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

AddAlarmActivity:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addalarm);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    AlarmList = (List<Alarm>) intent.getSerializableExtra("AlarmList");

    MyTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    MyTimePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

    ringtoneLabel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText_RingtoneUri);
    ringtoneLabel.setEnabled(false);

    ringtoneUri = null;


    for (Alarm x: AlarmList) {
        // Debugging
        Toast.makeText(AddAlarmActivity.this, "" + x.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I want to take my List, send it with the Intent, recieve it in the other Activity and check it's contents with the loop. I later want to send the list back to MainActivity after modifying it.

I added some dummy data to the list, just to see if anything gets sent at all. But now the app just crashes whenever I click on the "AddAlarm" button.

In order to make sure that some other Intent isn't starting the Activity and messing everything up I added the check `intent.hasExtra("AlarmList")` I figured that that would make sure that I don't get some strange data.

I am currently using my DeleteAlarm Button for debugging. If I run the app and click on the DeleteAlarm Button it starts toasting "id1", "id2", "id3" - so that part works as intended.

Here is the crash log:

> 09-17 11:03:19.958 28930-28930/com.example.alarmclock E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         Process: com.example.alarmclock, PID: 28930
>                                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19959)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5596)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19959) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5596) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.persson.peter.alarmclock.Alarm@3982ba66
>                                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1343)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:717)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1290)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644)
>                                                                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1320)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1036)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669)
>                                                                                             at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7531)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2447)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1496)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3843)
>                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
>                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3797)
>                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4114)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4082)
>                                                                                             at com.example.persson.peter.alarmclock.MainActivity.addAlarm_Click(MainActivity.java:65)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19959) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5596) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Try to let `Alarm` class  implement `Serializable` .

Comment: @KeLiuyue I added "implements Serializable". Still crashes. Seems to be same crash log.

Comment: You can try my answer.@Phrosen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use serializable because you can serialize you model Alarm but inside your alarm, you are using Uri object.

Uri object is `Parcelable` not `Serializable` so it like boilerplate.

You better implement Parcelable in your Alarm class.

Your Alarm class should be like this:

```
public class Alarm implements Parcelable {
    public static final Creator<Alarm> CREATOR = new Creator<Alarm>() {
        @Override
        public Alarm createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Alarm(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Alarm[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Alarm[size];
        }
    };
    private String Name;
    private List<String> Days;
    private String Id;
    private int Hour;
    private int Minute;
    private Uri Ringtone;

    public Alarm(String newId, String newName, int newHour, int newMinute, Uri newRingtone, List<String> newDaysList) {
        setId(newId);
        setName(newName);
        setHour(newHour);
        setMinute(newMinute);
        setRingtone(newRingtone);
        setDays(newDaysList);
    }

    protected Alarm(Parcel in) {
        Name = in.readString();
        Days = in.createStringArrayList();
        Id = in.readString();
        Hour = in.readInt();
        Minute = in.readInt();
        Ringtone = in.readParcelable(Uri.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        Name = newName;
    }

    public List<String> getDays() {
        return Days;
    }

    public void setDays(List<String> newDaysList) {
        Days = newDaysList;
    }

    public void addDay(String newDay) {
        Days.add(newDay);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String newId) {
        Id = newId;
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return Hour;
    }

    public void setHour(int newHour) {
        Hour = newHour;
    }

    public int getMinute() {
        return Minute;
    }

    public void setMinute(int newMinute) {
        Minute = newMinute;
    }

    public Uri getRingtone() {
        return Ringtone;
    }

    public void setRingtone(Uri newRingtone) {
        Ringtone = newRingtone;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(Name);
        dest.writeStringList(Days);
        dest.writeString(Id);
        dest.writeInt(Hour);
        dest.writeInt(Minute);
        dest.writeParcelable(Ringtone, flags);
    }
}
```

You can get the Arraylist at receiver activity like this:

```
ArrayList<Alarm> parcelableArrayListExtra = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

1. Let `Alarm` class implement `Parcelable` .
2. use `Intent` and `Bundle`

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddAlarmActivity.class);
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
   //add list to Bundle
   bundle.putParcelableArrayList("AlarmList", AlarmList);  
   // add Bundle to intent
   intent.putExtras(bundle);  
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
3. In the next Activity

   ```
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   ArrayList<Alarm> list = bundle.getParcelableArrayListExtra("AlarmList");
   ```